# Check a date of a file against todays date

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to compare a file modified date on Sharepoint against today's date & if it matches then do another task. The below code works & gives me the date of Fri Mar 10 12:01:45 2017 for the file. How do I get todays date in the same format to compare the dates in a IF statement?

```
import os, time, datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
FILE = "//website.com/file.xlsx"
date = strftime("%a %b %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(FILE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the below code to get it work!!!

```
 import os, time
 import datetime
 from time import gmtime, strftime
 FILE = "//website.com/file.xlsx"
 NOW = strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

 MOD = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y", time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(FILE)))

 print NOW
 print MOD
 print NOW == MOD
```